# How can I transform an XML config file with a build task in DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights

In my .NET Framework application I need to vary the Application Insights `InstrumentationKey` in `ApplicationInsights.config` as part of the build for different environments (Dev, UAT etc).

In my solution I have a `ApplicationInsights.config` file that does not contain the `InstumentationKey`

I also have an `ApplicationInsights.Dev.config` transformation file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"
                     xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <InstrumentationKey>89c95f9d-0f89-41cb-938b-175499e3052a</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

In my pipeline YAML I have the following step:

```
        - task: FileTransform@1
          inputs:
            folderPath: 'path/to/directory' 
            enableXmlTransform: true
            xmlTransformationRules: '-transform ApplicationInsights.Dev.config -xml ApplicationInsights.config'
```

The build task completes but when I look at the resulting `ApplicationInsight.config` file in the work directory the `InstrumentationKey` is not present.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace InstrumentationKey your ApplicationInsight.Config should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"
                     xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <InstrumentationKey>89c95f9d-0f89-41cb-938b-175499e3052a</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

and your tranformation config `ApplicationInsights.Dev.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on using app.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
<!-- In case configuration is not the root element, replace it with root element in source configuration file -->
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <InstrumentationKey xdt:Transform="Replace">
        Value for dev
    </InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

and then for such pipeline:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/76-config-transform/
    enableXmlTransform: true
    xmlTransformationRules: '-transform ApplicationInsights.Dev.config -xml ApplicationInsights.config'
- bash: cat ApplicationInsights.config
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/76-config-transform/
```

you will get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I need to vary the Application Insights InstrumentationKey in ApplicationInsights.config as part of the build for different environments

To transform XML config file, you need specify the transform attribute syntax in your `ApplicationInsights.Dev.config` file.

Since your `ApplicationInsights.config` file that does not contain the `InstumentationKey`, you should use the transform attribute `Insert`, `xdt:Transform="Insert"`:

```
<InstrumentationKey xdt:Transform="Insert">89c95f9d-0f89-41cb-938b-175499e3052a</InstrumentationKey>
```

Please check the document [Transformation Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)#syntax-4) for some more details.

The `ApplicationInsights.Dev.config` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"
                     xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <InstrumentationKey xdt:Transform="Insert">89c95f9d-0f89-41cb-938b-175499e3052a</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

The test result:

[image]